# input select iphone causing page jump

Tags: javascript, html, iphone

When I try the following code on iphone , after clicking copy button, it looks like a page jump (It doesnt happen on android). Code is copied successfuly (you can test by pasting), but I want to get rid of this "page jump". I think it must be hapenning because of calling select().

```js
document.getElementById('copy').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  var data = 'fooo'

  var dummy = document.createElement("input");
  dummy.setAttribute("id", "copy-url");
  document.body.appendChild(dummy);
  document.getElementById("copy-url").value = data;
  dummy.select();
  try {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  } catch (er) {}
  document.body.removeChild(dummy);

})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="copy"> copy me</button>
```

Comment: I don't understand wdym by "page jump"?

Comment: Well,  I have written in the poost that you need to test on iphone, otherwise you cant see the problem.

Comment: can you screen record the "page jump"? Also try setting a fixed width and height to the html `body` using css. see if that changes anything.

Comment: I cannot chnage any settings for the body or anything like that becuase this is just part of the page (it cannot change page behavior). Could be something with iphone behavior (there are similar threads with "input focus iphone")